# encasing div and anchor link binded to same event

Tags: jquery, events, event-bubbling

im having trouble figuring out how to bind mouseout() to my entire nav bar including the links.

when a user hovers over a link in #nav a sub menu is shown.  all is well there.

what i want to do is fadeOut that sub menu when the user hovers out of the entire #nav.

my code for the mouseout:

```
$('#nav').mouseout(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
   //$('.sub-link').fadeOut();
  }, 2000);
});
```

when i hover over an anchor link which resides in #nav, i see the sub-menu.  then i guess the mouseout() even fires and the sub-menu fades out.  is there anyway to have the #nav and any anchor links within it to act as one?

i'd paste my markup but even indenting it 4 spaces still shows as rendered html..

sample page at: http://chrisparaiso.com/test/

Comment: got it!  mouseleave() works.  weird i find the answer 2 mins after posting the darn question after 1 hour searching.

edit:  wait this stopped working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) should be what you need:

```
$('#nav').mouseleave(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
   $('.sub-link').fadeOut();
  }, 2000);
});
```

From the documentation:

> The mouseleave event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the element it is bound to, **not a descendant**.

You are right that `mouseout` is triggered if the cursor is over an element inside the element you bound the event to. But `mouseleave` is really only triggered when the cursor leaves the while element.

[This example](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/#example-0) demonstrates very the the differences between `mouseleave()` and `mouseout()`.

Comment: I found this function minutes after posting my question..  it seemed to work at first, but then it just started doing the same thing. :(

Comment: @centr0: If you can provide a link to a sample page, we might be able to help further.

Comment: @centr0: Ok, I see. The problem is that the submenu is not contained in the navbar anymore (due to visibility stuff). An idea is to make `#nav` as heigh that it encapsulates the sub-menus and create the background color effect (the grey bar) with another `div` that surrounds the main menu list.

Comment: Awesome!  it worked.  never thought it would be a css problem, but it makes sense!  Thanks for taking the time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a selector like `$('#nav, #nav > a')`